# Set a dynamic value for the "disabled" parameter of the struts radio

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, radio-button, struts

so i am tring to create a struts radio that will show elements (throught a list passed into the parameters "list" and "listKey".
What i am trying to add to that is that some radios will be read-only (based on some field declared on a server-side bean).

So struts radio is like this in the jsp :

```xml
<s:radio id="radioStatutType" 
       name="radioStatutType" 
      theme="extend" 
templateDir="template"
       list="statList" 
    listKey="myId" 
  listValue="label" 
    onclick="checkType();" 
   disabled="disabRgt" />
```

So the fields "myId" and "label" are declared in the same bean and they both work perfectly (so the scope is correct i think).

Same as these two fields, i declared a String named "disabRgt" (in the bean) that is filled with true/false (with a toString on a boolean calculated with some code). I declared the setter and getter but when displaying the jsp (and the radio) this field is not used (i verified throught debug watchpoint access/modification).

So i changed this field into boolean (primitive) and it did not work. Finally, i changed the getter into "isDisabRgt" instead of "getDisabRgt" => Same result ..

So it seems that the field "disabRgt" is never evaluated and that the "disabled" parameter in the radio is always filled with the default value (which is false).

Hope i explained it well ! Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you want to disable only some of radio buttons in `statList`?

Comment: @AleksandrM Yes ! I just want to disable some of radio buttons in the statList.

Answer (score 2):

Since `disabled="%{myBoolean}"` doesn't evaluate the expression, you must do it in some other way:

- Using `<s:if>` on the variable to display the radio enabled or disabled:

  ```xml
  <s:if test="%{disabRgt}">
      <s:radio ... disabled="true" >
  </s:if>
  <s:else>
      <s:radio ... >
  </s:else>
  ```
- Disabling it with Javascript:

  ```xml
  <script>
      $(function() {
          if (<s:property value="%{disabRgt}"/>){
              $("#radioStatutType").prop( "disabled", true );
          }
      });
  </script>
  ```

Just remember to always use booleans, never voodoos like Boolean's `toString()`s ;)

Comment: Good. Don't forget to upvote the answer if you liked it and to accept it if it solved your problem, thank you

Comment: Hey again ! Unfortunatly what this does is to enable or disable all the radios :( What i want to do si to enable/disable some of the radios using the field "disabRgt" (that will be evaluated relatively to each radio at every iteration)